# make selecting color transparent so that image can be seen

Tags: angular

I am trying to paint on an image. for this purpose, I am using [ng2-canvas-whiteboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-canvas-whiteboard)

though it is painting on an image, however I am not able to see the image building boundaries.

I tried to put opacity but it is also not working probably because, I do not need to make the element on which I am drawing transparent but the color which I am using, I need to make them transparent.

I also tried to edit ng2-canvas-whiteboard component and added opacity to every color but it was also not working.
[image]

this is [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-mqsxv7?file=app/app.module.ts)

html

```
<div style="height: 400px">
    <canvas-whiteboard class="transparent-style" #canvasWhiteboard [imageUrl]="url" [drawButtonClass]="'drawButtonClass'" [drawButtonText]="'Draw'" [clearButtonClass]="'clearButtonClass'" [clearButtonText]="'Clear'" [undoButtonText]="'Undo'" [undoButtonEnabled]="true"
        [redoButtonText]="'Redo'" [redoButtonEnabled]="true" [colorPickerEnabled]="true" (onBatchUpdate)="sendBatchUpdate($event)" [lineWidth]="15" (onClear)="onCanvasClear()" (onUndo)="onCanvasUndo($event)" (onRedo)="onCanvasRedo($event)">
    </canvas-whiteboard>
</div>
```

ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "app";
  url = "https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX4293964.jpg";

  sendBatchUpdate(updates: CanvasWhiteboardUpdate[]) {
    console.log(updates);
  }
  onCanvasClear() {
    console.log("The canvas was cleared");
  }
  onCanvasUndo(updateUUID: string) {
    console.log(`UNDO with uuid: ${updateUUID}`);
  }
  onCanvasRedo(updateUUID: string) {
    console.log(`REDO with uuid: ${updateUUID}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stokeColor property (i.e [strokeColor]="'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'").
But only one color will be selected by using this property, changing the color will remove the transparency.

What I did in my last project is forked the ng2-canvas-whiteboard and updated it as I wanted and used in my project. You can do the same.

For color modifications:

File that needs to be modified : ng2-canvas-whiteboard/dist/canvas-whiteboard-colorpicker.component.js

Function: createColorPalette

Change : Modify all colors by providing transparency value.

Note: If mouse is pressed for few seconds transparency will be lost. Please use stoke color property to see the affect before modifying all the function.

Hope this helps :)